list comprehension if keyword in string
I am cleaning columns in a dataframe, and would like to split a "description" column based on certain keywords. I wrote a one liner but for some reason in still returns np.nan, even when the condition is met.
def find_and_suck_hashtag_vacuum(string, keyword, output):
    return [output if keyword in string else np.nan]

with the variables set as
string_samp = ['Air conditioning,Car park,Interesting wine list,Restaurant offering vegetarian menus,Wheelchair access']

output = find_and_suck_hashtag_vacuum(string_samp, "Air", "AC")

But the function still returns np.nan in the above case. What should I modify?

string_samp only contains one string. The commas are not separating elements, they're just part of that one element.

It should be string_samp = ['Air conditioning', 'Car park', 'Interesting wine list', 'Restaurant offering vegetarian menus', 'Wheelchair access']

You don't have a list comprehension. You're missing the for <variable> in <list> part

string_samp is a list that contains one string.  The exact string "Air" is not a member of that list, so the else case is chosen.

@JohnGordon Right, because they forgot to loop over the items in the list with a list comprehension.

In the question you say you want to "split" the description. But you never do that. Use df['colname'].str.split(',') in pandas for that.

well I'll just douse my head in cold water, haha. thanks for the candor. guessing there's no way to use simple syntax for the "smallerstring" in "muchlargerstring" case?

Your function seems like it should return just one value -- either output or np.nan.  Why do you need a list?

I came to the same solution, it now outputs a single value

I will leave my answer as the syntax may be helpful for someone in the future. On a separate note, my question remains about finding smallers strings in larger strings - I forget, is it always necessary to split into values in a list before searching? ...Or is that regex...

string1 in string2 is the straightforward way to check if one string occurs inside another.

Or, if you have a list of strings, any(word in phrase for phrase in list_of_phrases)

so for this case that would be "if 'Air' in string samp" ?

I can't answer that, because I don't know if string_samp is correctly represented in the question.  As it's written, string_samp is a list that contains exactly one string.  Is that actually correct?  (And if so, why?  Why do you have a list that contains a single string?  Why not just have a plain string?)

as to why it's not separate stings, data cleaning woes. as to why it's wrapped in a list, was trying to remember the right way to clean strings that need to be grouped into categories. it's wrong.

it's going to end up being a pandas explode call

any(keyword in phrase for phrase in string[0].split(','))

Your input is a list of string, and not a string. So the code determines that the string "Air" is not an element in the list. Working code would be:
string_samp = ['Air conditioning,Car park,Interesting wine list,Restaurant offering vegetarian menus,Wheelchair access']

output = find_and_suck_hashtag_vacuum(string_samp[0], "Air", "AC")


solution, actually using list comprehension:
def find_and_suck_hashtag_vacuum(string, keyword, output):
    return [output if keyword in j else np.nan for j in string_samp.split(",")]

Thanks both.
